# Dockerfile ADD . is adding wrong directory

Tags: django, docker

```
.
|-- business_logic
|   ....
|
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- src
|   `-- backend
|       |-- Dockerfile
|       |-- manage.py
|       |-- requirements.txt
|       `-- webapp
|           |-- __init__.py
|           |-- settings.py
|           |-- urls.py
|           `-- wsgi.py
`-- utils.py
```

I want Docker to copy *./src/backend/* to */code/* on the container and when I'm running this compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build:
      context: ./src/backend/
    command: ls -l .
    volumes:
      - .:/code/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

With the Dockerfile under *backend*:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /code/
```

I would expect that the Dockerfile-position in the file tree or the context would be the relative path "." in the `Dockerfile`, but it seems as if "." points to the directory where `docker-compose.yml` lies. Because the output is following:

```
web_1  | drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 448 Jan  2 01:51 business_logic
web_1  | -rw-r--r--  1 root root 207 Jan  2 03:10 docker-compose.yml
web_1  | drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  96 Jan  2 02:34 src
web_1  | -rw-r--r--  1 root root 657 Jan  2 01:51 utils.py
```

How to copy only everything below the *backend*-folder into *code*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In docker-compose when you are using volume to map it is mapping your current directory (which is in parallel with docker-compose.yml) , however in case of Dockerfile "." means current directory with respect to docker-context (./src/backend/) that you set.

Here after Docker image preparation, while creating container volume is causing override.
*hint - Use the same docker-context first and then adjust paths accordingly.*

Try following docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3'

    services:
      db:
        image: postgres
      web:
        build:
          context: ./src/backend/
        command: ls -l .
        volumes:
          - ./src/backend/:/code/
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
          - db
```

Comment: (To answer the question implied by the title: `ADD` is working correctly, but your `volumes:` line is hiding the work the Dockerfile does.)

Comment: And how to remove the overwriting of the Dockerfile location? Without doing it explicitly?